# Redirecting after user login with modal form on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes

Instead of a single login page, I'm using a modal for user login. I want to redirect logged in user to the page where modal form opened.

I tried to modify `LoginController` with `return Redirect::back();` but it returned with "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected".

This is my modified `LoginController.php`

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return Redirect::back();
}
```

Maybe I'm following completely wrong way to  do that. So I'm open for any suggestion. Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`

Override the `authenticated` function with this:

```php
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
    return redirect('/'.$request->path());
}
```

The `$request->path()` will retrieve the request origin path.

**@Edit to see the owner's comment in another answer**

To also get the url parameter, such as `/...?p=477`.
You can edit your modal authentication form to have this hidden input:

```php
<input type="hidden" name="current_page" value="{{Request::getRequestUri()}}">
```

In this way, in your `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`

Override the `authenticated` function with this:

```php
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
    return redirect($request['current_page']);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It must be "use Illuminate\Http\Request" instead of "Env\Request". After this change this is my logincontroller

protected function redirectTo(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect($request['current_page']);
    }

And it worked. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `Redirect::back()`, just use `redirect('/your_page_where_modal_appears')`

Comment: Thanks for advice but like I said there are hundreds of posts. I don't want to redirect to a static page. I want to redirect user to the page that he loggeg in. For example if he want to log in, in the page url .../?p=477 after a successfull login process, I want to redirect him back to the p=477. And the problem is that; I don't have any idea how to do that.